# "#This Row" gives run-time error when selecting other cell in current row of Excel table with VBA - BUG?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have:

- Excel 2013
- **one table** called "TableA"
- with **three columns** (the column headers are "Bit", "Byte" and "Kilo")
- and several **rows** of random data

When the macro starts, a single cell in any given row might be selected and I want to return the value of the corresponding cell *in the same row* but in column "Bit".

Excel has the feature to reference table cells like this

```
TableA[[#This Row], [Bit]]
```

where "Bit" is a column, which would do the trick perfectly. **However, it doesn't seem to work in VBA!**
For example this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("TableA[[#This Row], [Bit]]").Select
```

results in *"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"*

Alternatively, I thought something like this might work:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells("TableA[Bit]", ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

but it also fails, with *"Run-time error 13: Type mismatch"*

**Do you know another working, simple way to select a cell in a table by referencing the wanted column header/title plus the row of the currently selected cell?**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[TableA[@Bit]].Select
```

or this

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("TableA[Bit]").Column).Select
```

Comment: You mean like
ActiveSheet.Range("TableA[@Bit]").Select
...?
still 1004 run-time error unfortunately :-(

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I typed.  (Tested and working in Excel 2010, sorry, don't have 2013 to test on)

Comment: Thanks ever so much! Got it now... strange though, that it doesn't work with #This Row, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this ..

```
 Sub TableA()
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Set oSh = ActiveSheet
    With oSh.ListObjects("TableA")
    'Select entire table
        .Range.Select
        'Select just the data of the entire table
        .DataBodyRange.Select
        'Select third column
        .ListColumns(3).Range.Select
        'Select only data of first column
        .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Select
         'Select just row 4 (header row doesn't count!)
        .ListRows(4).Range.Select
    End With
End Sub
```